# When am I required to call Marshal.ReleaseComObject on an interface queried through COM in C#

Tags: c#, com, interop

I have been working with some DirectShow interfaces for playing Digital TV (DVB-T) using C# and [DirectShow.Net](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/). I recently encountered the runtime error `COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.`

This error occurred in the following line:

`_guideData = _transportInformationFilter as IGuideData;`

`_transportInformationFilter` is of type IBaseFilter, a COM object previously assigned via a DirectShow.Net utility function.

I assumed the error was due to `_transportInformationFilter` somehow being prematurely released, and I traced it to the following method (error handling removed):

```
private void AttachGuideDataEvent()
{
    IConnectionPoint connPoint = null;
    IConnectionPointContainer connPointContainer = null;
    try
    {
        connPointContainer = _transportInformationFilter as IConnectionPointContainer;
        if (connPointContainer == null) /* error */

        var guideDataEventGuid = typeof (IGuideDataEvent).GUID;
        connPointContainer.FindConnectionPoint(ref guideDataEventGuid, out connPoint);
        if (connPoint == null) /* error */

        int cookie;
        connPoint.Advise(this, out cookie);
        if (cookie == 0) /* error */    
        _persistIGuideDataEventCookie = cookie;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connPointContainer != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(connPointContainer);
        if (connPoint != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(connPoint);
    }
}
```

As I understood it, `connPointContainer = _transportInformationFilter as IConnectionPointContainer` should have resulted in a call to `QueryInterface` on the `_transportInformationFilter` COM object, and thus would need to be released separately. However, the call to `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(connPointContainer)` was the culprit causing `_transportInformationFilter` to be separated from its RCW; removing this call fixed the issue.

Given this, **in what situations am I required to explicitly release COM objects (using `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`) in C# to avoid leaking resources?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Almost never. ReleaseComObject manages the reference count of the RCW, not the underlying object and is not directly analogous to `IUnknown.Release`. You should let the CLR manage its `QueryInterface`'ing and `Release`'ing.

> The RCW has a reference count that is incremented every time a COM interface pointer is mapped to it. The ReleaseComObject method decrements the reference count of an RCW. When the reference count reaches zero, the runtime releases all its references on the unmanaged COM object, and throws a System.NullReferenceException if you attempt to use the object further. If the same COM interface is passed more than one time from unmanaged to managed code, the reference count on the wrapper is incremented every time, and calling ReleaseComObject returns the number of remaining references.

...

> This method enables you to force an RCW reference count release so that it occurs precisely when you want it to. However, improper use of ReleaseComObject may cause your application to fail, or may cause an access violation.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx

FYI, the way to call `IUnknown.Release` directly is [`Marshal.Release`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.release.aspx), not `ReleaseComObject`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If the MSDN docs say that the caller is specifically responsible for releasing a returned interface (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692476(VS.85).aspx), will the runtime manage the call to Release for me when the object is out of scope, or is that a situation I should use ReleaseComObject?

Comment: Well it doesn't operate when the object "goes out of scope" but rather when the finalizer for the RCW runs, so for the case of connPoint, it doesn't hurt. The important thing to keep in mind is that `ReleaseComObject` operates on the RCW, it is like calling `Dispose`, and it broke for similar reasons that `a = _member as IFoo ; a.Dispose(); _member.DoSomething()` might break.

Comment: @Logan: do you have some references for 'almost never' it seems that my fellow coder can't stand this kind of uncertainty (he is new to .NET)

Comment: @Daniel This answer could be written more clearly. If you're trying to manage the reference count (AddRef/Release) of a COM object you should not do that, and if you want to deterministically release a COM object you should most likely be using FinalReleaseComObject. The reference is pretty much the docs for ReleaseComObject, which I aleady linked to. "...Therefore, use the ReleaseComObject only if it is absolutely required."

Comment: Nope, it is generally a good practice to always release it. I was iterating over COM objects in a loop and it threw an exception when you didn't call Release explicitly.

Answer (score 8):

I think I've found a truly legitimate circumstance for using Marshal.ReleaseComObject. When writing excel addins in C# using ExcelDNA, I tend to use COM interop from worker threads, and access excel automation objects like "Application", "Workbook" etc.

If I waited for the garbage collector to finalize these objects, what I would have is an invisible excel "zombie" instance remaining in the task manager after the user exits excel. This is because those RCW's keep excel alive, and they can stay running for quite some time.